# Programmatically add buttons to a Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml

I've created a project with scrollable tabs. Each tab is declared by a fragment. And now i want f.e. Fragment1 to have 8 Buttons in it, Fragment2 4 Buttons and so on. I want to have rows, each containing a maximum of three buttons, so if i spawn 4 buttons there should be one row with 3 buttons and one row with 1 Button under it. So this is how i make scrollable tabs:

My Main_Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ViewPager viewPager = null;
    SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer();
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceStats)
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceStats);
       setContentView(R.layout.homescreen);
       viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
       FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
       viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));
   }
}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if(position == 0)
            fragment = new FragmentDominik();
        else if(position == 1)
            fragment = new FragmentTobias();
        else if(position == 2)
            fragment = new FragmentTom();
        else if(position == 3)
            fragment = new FragmentNikolas();
        else if(position == 4)
            fragment = new FragmentGroups();
        else if(position == 5)
            fragment = new FragmentOthers();
        else if(position == 6)
            fragment = new FragmentFavorites();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 7;
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        String title = new String();
        if(position == 0)
            return "Dominik";
        else if(position == 1)
            return "Tobias";
        else if(position == 2)
            return "Tom";
        else if(position == 3)
            return "Nikolas";
        else if(position == 4)
            return "Groups";
        else if(position == 5)
            return "Others";
        else if(position == 6)
            return "Favorites";
        return null;
    }
}
```

My homescreen.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:background="#4052b5"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

One example Fragment.java

```
public class FragmentTobias extends Fragment {

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tobias, container, false);
        }
    }
```

One example Fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#d1d1d1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Tobias"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

so now if i want to spawn a number of 8 buttons in tobias.xml, porgrammatically in FragmentTobias.java, how would i do this? I'm kind of new to creating android apps, so any help is appreciated.

Edit1:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params1);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); //or VERTICAL

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        Button button = new Button(getActivity());
        button.setLayoutParams(params2);

        Button button2 = new Button(getActivity());
        button2.setLayoutParams(params2);

        //like this, add all buttons and other views
        //you can use a loop for adding multiple similar views

        linearLayout.addView(button);
        linearLayout.addView(button2);
        container.addView(linearLayout);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically add buttons to `ViewGroup` and inflate your view using it. Try the following code,

```
public class FragmentTobias extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); //or VERTICAL

        LayoutParams buttonParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        Button button = new Button(getActivity());
        button.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);

        Button button2 = new Button(getActivity());
        button2.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);

        linearLayout.addView(button);
        linearLayout.addView(button2);

        //like this, add all buttons and other views
        //you can use a loop for adding multiple similar views

        container.addView(linearLayout);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tobias, container, false);

        return view;
    }
}
```